# How to receive AltNumber in ANTLR?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4

I'm going to use ANTLR 4.5.3 for translating one notation to another. I have already designed grammar description using plugin in IntelliJ IDEA.

In my grammar one rule has several alternatives.

When I'm looking at the results in "Parse Tree" each node consists of "rule name" : "row number".

How to receive this information using API? If I understand it clearly, row number could be retrieved from getAltNumber(), but this field is empty.

http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/RuleContext.html#getAltNumber()

In the docs is said that default implementation does not compute nor store this alt num.

How to get this information?

Comment: Using "alternate labeling" (TDAR pg 117, 261) would be a better approach. Otherwise subclass as suggested by the `#getAltNumber` doc -- FWIW, have never needed to do this.

Comment: Are you sure the row number means the alt number? To me it sounds like it would be the line number in the source code. But then I don't know the IntelliJ output for ANTLR grammars. If you need the line number, well, call getLine() :-)

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem. The documentation should be a little more precise, but indeed it gives a clue. Also looking directly at the plugin may lead to the solution:
https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/blob/master/src/java/org/antlr/intellij/plugin/preview/AltLabelTextProvider.java

You may simply add a context super class implementing setAltNumber and getAltNumber as in example:
https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/tool/GrammarInterpreterRuleContext.java

Then provide the class as a generator parameter, e.g.:

> antlr4 -o output/path -listener -visitor -DcontextSuperClass=GrammarInterpreterRuleContext -Dlanguage=Java -lib lib/path grammar.g4

Comment: Or in the c++ runtime: `-DcontextSuperClass=antlr4::RuleContextWithAltNum`

Comment: Though unfortunately as of this writing the cpp runtime doesn't populate the altNumber in all cases.